# Different contentType with same status code in Azure Function OpenApi Specification

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, openapi

Here when you pay attention to `OpenApiResponseWithBody` the result gives an error

Please note: The response code I am expecting is same for either of the response content type.

```
[OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK, contentType: "application/xml", bodyType: typeof(Whatever), Description = "XML response")]
[OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK, contentType: "application/json", bodyType: typeof(Whatever), Description = "The JSON response")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req)
{
    return ...
}
```

Error states

```
An item with the same key has already been added. Key: 200
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core.DocumentHelper.GetOpenApiResponses(MethodInfo element, NamingStrategy namingStrategy, VisitorCollection collection, OpenApiVersionType version)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Document.Build(Assembly assembly, OpenApiVersionType version)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.OpenApiTriggerFunctions.RenderSwaggerDocument(OpenApiHttpTriggerContext openApiContext, HttpRequest req, String extension, ExecutionContext ctx, ILogger log)
```

Whereas my assumtion is to get resultant yaml with something like this

```
responses:
     '200':
       description: A Whatever
       content:
         application/json:
            schema:
              ...
         application/xml:
            schema:
              ...
```

Answer (score 0):

- I think the issue is with having the same status code. As far as I know you can have multiple `OpenApiResponseWithBody` but with different status code.
- So, you have multiple `OpenApiResponseWithBody` one with status code `200` other maybe with status code `202` and so on.

Here,  I have multiple `OpenApiResponseWithBody`:-

```
[OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK, contentType: "application/xml", bodyType: typeof(string), Description = "xml")]
[OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.Accepted, contentType: "application/json", bodyType: typeof(string), Description = "json")]
```

[image]

`swagger.yaml`  :

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: OpenAPI Document on Azure Functions
  version: 1.0.0
host: localhost:7286
basePath: /api
schemes:
  - http
paths:
  /Function1:
    get:
      tags:
        - name
      operationId: Run
      produces:
        - application/xml
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: name
          description: The **Name** parameter
          required: true
          type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: xml
          schema:
            type: string
        '202':
          description: json
          schema:
            type: string
      security:
        - function_key: [ ]
securityDefinitions:
  function_key:
    type: apiKey
    name: code
    in: query
```

Comment: Please note: The response code I am expecting is same for either of the response content type.